# Sending Transaction From the created contract address

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I am trying to deploy my Roadmap contract from the address of another newly built contract with Truffle.
I tried to do something like this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
      deployer.deploy(MilestoneBased, RoadmapDelegate.address).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(Roadmap, {from: MilestoneBased.address});
  });
```

But I'm receiving an error "Sender account not recognized". How could I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deploy contracts from another contract like that.

Basically what you need to do is include the contract creation inside the contract. So it has to have a function which creates another contract with something like: `OtherContract c = new OtherContract(constructorArguments);`. Obviously you need to have the contract  `OtherContract`definition available inside the contract.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But isn't there anyway, that we could grant access to the platform to send transactions from that contract?

Comment: No. A transaction is always sent from an EOA (Externally Owned Account).

Comment: Just a quick question, Will I be able to see the contract in Ganache if we create it inside the contract(the way that you said above)?

Comment: Well, everything happening in the blockchain is public, but some of the data may be difficult to interpret. I'm not sure how you'll see it in Ganache - at least you'll see the sub-contract address in some fashion.